# Making a clickable <div> accessible through tab structure?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wcag2.0

So I am working on a project that requires a `<div>` with an onclick event. I've got the main functionality working, but there is one problem. I need the onclick event to happen when the user tabs to the `<div>` and presses enter. I added a tabindex to the `<div>` which allows it to gain focus, but nothing happens when the user presses enter (or any other key).

Can anyone help me with this? Or is what I want not even possible?

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/logiwan992/suwq7r09/

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Send your code please.!!!

Comment: @Mxxpersian: It's in the JSFiddle.

Comment: Learn about [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/).

Comment: This work fine For me !!!!

Comment: Wrap that div in an anchor dog. It's more semantic and will simplify your code.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell How is using an anchor in this case more semantic?

Comment: @divinecomedian screenreaders don't know you're attaching anchor-like functionality to a div (unless you start adding ARIA markup to tell them about it... but an anchor is easier)

Comment: Because and anchor has assumed click functionality. A screen reader doesn't know when you attached a click handler to an element. The browser doesn't know you can tab to the element unless you add a tab index. So after you add a click and focus handler, alter the HTML to include an incorrect tab index (is that DIV really the first thing the user should tab to on the page?) add in all the aria tags to get screen readers to understand that the element should be treated like an anchor, what are you left with? Seems easier to add another element or just change the DIV itself to an anchor.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell I see.  You definitely make a good case for making the code easier.  But how do you know the OP wants the `div` to be semantically equivalent to an anchor?  He didn't mention using it to link to a resource, which is what anchors are for, so it wouldn't be more semantic.

Comment: The more semantic option would be a `<button>` tag.

Comment: If you have to keep with a div with onclick then you can add a onkeypress with the same command to accept keyboard input

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I note the question is tagged WCAG and "accessibility".

The answer to your question is therefore "don't do that."  The other answers on this page will all work fine, for everyone except the people who need it to work, i.e. those using screenreaders or other assistive technology.  None of the javascript-based solutions here are WCAG compliant.

What you want is a `<button>`.  That gives you your tabindex and keyboard control for free.

You can also force a `<div>` to work like a `<button>` by adding ARIA markup (though it's better and easier to just use the tag that already does what you need it to do.)

If absolutely necessary, a good introduction to using ARIA for pseudo-buttons is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role

The gist of it is, you need to add the `role="button"` attribute, and manage the state of the `aria-pressed` attribute manually (by capturing key events and clicks in javascript; other answers have covered this pretty thoroughly so I won't repeat the details)

Comment: The problem here is that I am working with legacy code. If I change the `<div>` to a `<button>` then all of the styling gets completely messed up. I don't know anything about ARIA markup, but can you explain how I could use it? I do agree that the "best" option would be to change it to a `<button>`. That is probably what I will end up doing in the end. It will just take a lot more work.

Comment: If you're working with legacy code then I'm willing to bet the whole darn thing is inaccessible.

Comment: @Logiwan992 : A `<button>` can contain any markup you want, so maybe you can wrap a button tag around your existing `<div>` rather than replace the div with a button.

Comment: *I note the question is tagged WCAG and "accessibility". The answer to your question is therefore "don't do that."* Oh my god, you read my mind...

Comment: @Logiwan992 I added some more info about ARIA -- I really suspect you'll find it less work to use a `<button>` and fix the CSS than to  reimplement it in a `<div>`, but ymmv

Comment: I did end up changing it to a `<button>`. Thank you for your help I think this was the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly fine to have a <div> work like a button provided you specify the right ARIA tags, roles, and keyboard events.  That's the whole point of ARIA.

I do agree, though, that when possible you should use the native html elements.  That's the first rule of ARIA use - http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#notes-on-aria-use-in-html.  But I understand that's not always possible.

There was a mention of using focus().  That's incorrect.  Focus() is used to *move* the focus to the object.  It's not used to handle an event.  Now perhaps they meant onFocus(), which is an event triggered when the object receives focus, but that's still not the right event to trap for.  You don't want a button (whether implemented as a <div> or a <button>) to perform its function just because you tabbed to it.  The user has to click or press enter/space on it.

Please look at the authoring practices which define the keyboard behavior for a button, http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#button, as well as the section that talks about keyboard events, http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#focus_tabindex.  In particular, note that you should *not* rely on keypress.  Not all browsers send that event.

Anytime you press a key, three possible events *might* happen:  Keydown, keypress, keyup.  Keydown and keyup are supported on all browsers and have access to event.keyCode.  Keypress is supported on some browser and has access to event.charCode.

There's a significant different between keyCode and charCode, especially if you're trying to implement shortcut keys such as Ctrl+/.  Many non-US keyboards have special keys in different places on the keyboard and you get different keyCodes for them.  But that's a topic for another discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind the `keypress` event on the said `div` and detect if `Enter` key was pressed (which has code number `13`).

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
div[0].addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('div focused');   
    }
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suwq7r09/5/)

---

You can, alternatively, use jQuery also:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('div').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert('div focused'); 
        }
    });

});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suwq7r09/1/)

Comment: this solution would require jQuery (not sure it was an original requirement) - but it should work with TAB (keycode '9') not ENTER

Comment: @ochi: Fair enough, I haven't noticed that jQuery was not in the OP tags.

Comment: I would like it to work without JQuery if at all possible, but I do want it to work with ENTER. First the div receives focus from TAB and then ENTER acts like a click on the div.

Comment: @ochi: Sure, but the OP wants to detect the press of the `Enter` key **on** the `div`. Element must have focus for the event handler to fire anyway so no need to detect `focus` or `TAB` key.

Comment: If it works with `Enter` it should also work with `Space` ... when using keyboard navigation either one of those will activate a button or link.

Comment: @StephenP: I'm not really that much into accessibility. Next time, I'll give more time into reading the tags linked to the question :)

Comment: @D4V1D : I'm into keeping my fingers on the keyboard because it's faster than reaching for the mouse, so I tab-then-space a lot to get to a button and press it - for example, type something in a field, tab to the submit button, press space when the button has focus.  And _**that's**_ why I know this behavior. 

Answer (score 1):

The "onclick" attribute has a specific behavior on links, because it can be triggered with the enter key.

See the following WCAG failure:
http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F59.html

You have to take care of the "role" of the element.

The following page illustrates how you can make an "accessible link" from a "span":
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_link_role

Also, as already said, best way is relying on a button/a element when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Give the element role="button" and tabindex="0" to make it focusable. Then detect an enter or space on any focused/active button. Turn that into a click.

Below is the html and jquery code for that. You only have to add this once and it works with all role=button elements.

```
<div role="button" tabindex="0">Do that thing</div>

$("body").on("keypress","[role='button']", function(e) { 
     if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32){ // 13=enter, 32=spacebar
         $(this).click();
         return false;
     }
})
```

I actually do this instead of using a proper `<button>` element. It avoids having to deal with overriding browser button styles. It also seems quite common, for example look at Gmail; so many clickable icons and settings and navigation buttons, and not a `<button>` in sight.

Answer (score -2):

Use the same event handler for both events.  If the event is `keypress` verify the key pressed is the Enter key before executing.

```js
var divButton = document.querySelector('#div-button');

divButton.addEventListener('click', activate);
divButton.addEventListener('keypress', activate);

function activate(e) {
  if (e.type === 'keypress' && e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('activated the div'); 
  }
};
```

```css
div {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

div:focus {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-button" tabindex="0">
    <h1>This is my div!</h1>
</div>
```